# Json to C# Object. Cant create proper class

Tags: c#, json.net

Im trying to deserialize JSON to C# object with Newtonsoft's JSON library ,but i cant create the proper class for it.I dont know why but i cant generate the class with json2sharp and etc.
Thats my JSON data:

```
[130,18063676,[["i",{"currencyPair":"XMR_BLK","orderBook":[{"0.00229667":"22.10045806","0.00229668":"2.24052467","0.00230580":"0.66824024","0.00231496":"1.82565395","0.00231688":"0.69843078","0.00232910":"0.72274387","0.00233835":"1.91615041","0.00234029":"0.70761459","0.00235264":"0.78457456","0.00235612":"0.26512460","0.00236198":"1.99131201","0.00236394":"0.71414743","0.00236971":"2686.26872112","0.00237641":"0.80664194","0.00238585":"2.11842456","0.00238663":"99.74479966","0.00238783":"1.36311792","0.00240042":"0.67445439","0.00240996":"1.94689294","0.00241196":"0.59385108","0.00242070":"0.23867946","0.00242465":"0.05000000","0.00242468":"0.70267761","0.00243431":"1.45608290","0.00243633":"0.65598162","0.00244918":"0.46293261","0.00246095":"0.54877121","0.00248000":"1234.56780000","0.00249156":"49.32038060","0.00250000":"1000.45724850","0.00251625":"77.83042125","0.00251974":"0.09016889","0.00252588":"108.50204529","0.00253185":"242.63870683","0.00253290":"0.21717548","0.00258146":"1.71513682","0.00267206":"0.11116944","0.00268206":"0.21289550","0.00273751":"2.92888705","0.00280100":"7.00000000","0.00283058":"0.18656785","0.00284419":"0.22062485","0.00288632":"257.62211104","0.00289000":"208.79511523","0.00290299":"4.54689042","0.00291409":"0.15000000","0.00291640":"0.05000000","0.00291641":"0.05000000","0.00292941":"0.25000000","0.00293043":"0.50000000","0.00298996":"0.05000000","0.00299156":"0.30000000","0.00299869":"0.36250000","0.00300100":"3.00000000","0.00301925":"2.85164408","0.00303055":"0.05000000","0.00303592":"0.10000000","0.00303711":"0.06051986","0.00305172":"0.16044203","0.00306561":"265.98613244","0.00310000":"26.82852923","0.00312151":"0.11531956","0.00317022":"55.62770365","0.00317027":"0.06617082","0.00318552":"0.15716959","0.00320100":"3.00000000","0.00321764":"99.75000000","0.00325837":"0.10552478","0.00330927":"0.11200707","0.00332519":"0.33746733","0.00335915":"0.16121328","0.00340100":"3.00000000","0.00341163":"0.13788443","0.00342804":"0.34566265","0.00346305":"0.19119985","0.00348756":"10.27346000","0.00350000":"31.45516070","0.00351715":"0.14172408","0.00352135":"5.00000000","0.00353407":"0.39862518","0.00357017":"0.22406321","0.00362594":"0.16048029","0.00364338":"0.40571532","0.00366104":"68.61752578","0.00368060":"0.23118789","0.00368750":"7.47534500","0.00373809":"0.17956392","0.00375607":"0.47237418","0.00379444":"0.47907211","0.00380100":"3.00000000","0.00387368":"0.14830488","0.00389231":"0.41361341","0.00390000":"1086.65812559","0.00393207":"0.22554964","0.00395340":"6.23640000","0.00396000":"1.33263674","0.00400000":"861.36424252","0.00401835":"0.74479806","0.00403768":"0.84085154","0.00407560":"7.34530000","0.00407892":"2.93798934","0.00424540":"5.45754000","0.00429312":"0.85462183","0.00431377":"1.02379072","0.00434391":"4.09559109","0.00448670":"6.43450000","0.00452135":"5.00000000","0.00456716":"1.27494102","0.00458913":"1.31893393","0.00459674":"5.81307351","0.00460000":"5.00000000","0.00462300":"541.00099775","0.00469450":"7.56753000","0.00478000":"80.28917709","0.00480000":"348.20000000","0.00485623":"1.57196462","0.00485869":"4.31681492","0.00486429":"5.58910584","0.00488740":"6.46740000","0.00490000":"3.00000000","0.00500000":"17.35633213","0.00509543":"5.05467000","0.00513888":"3.02645787","0.00514148":"5.03326419","0.00514741":"12.41074031","0.00515000":"10017.00000000","0.00527570":"5.05670000","0.00540000":"2.00000000","0.00543798":"1.16254591","0.00544073":"2.04827679","0.00544701":"4.94262448","0.00547860":"6.24740000","0.00548800":"2.00000000","0.00552135":"5.00000000","0.00568744":"7.74534000","0.00569000":"10.54481546","0.00576350":"1.96469354","0.00577015":"4.53722308","0.00578510":"1.03693487","0.00588394":"7.20627839","0.00588740":"7.45600000","0.00588800":"1.00000000","0.00598800":"1.00000000","0.00600000":"398.32786857","0.00609768":"5.04343670","0.00616416":"7.20627839","0.00616418":"0.77985772","0.00617129":"3.33704064","0.00618728":"1.35702493","0.00622801":"0.67897320","0.00623906":"0.77163865","0.00624626":"3.99974754","0.00626244":"1.39440606","0.00630000":"35.00000000","0.00630209":"0.88683339","0.00630936":"5.62758725","0.00632571":"1.93131866","0.00636576":"1.48357895","0.00637310":"7.60288981","0.00637649":"8.14339607","0.00638962":"2.12344370","0.00639564":"1.70809755","0.00639754":"1.96648654","0.00643007":"1.05513568","0.00645615":"2.96517668","0.00645705":"5.97278720","0.00645965":"1.94587971","0.00647379":"1.97248472","0.00648768":"1.32450000","0.00650000":"59.98500000","0.00650771":"7.20627839","0.00652135":"5.00000000","0.00652176":"1.96648661","0.00653000":"110.04350000","0.00656000":"20.00000000","0.00659542":"6.00000000","0.00661000":"10.00000000","0.00661398":"4.05360501","0.00664570":"7.56000000","0.00666000":"21.90307814","0.00666173":"4.40295148","0.00667021":"1.06107702","0.00669819":"5.77696118","0.00671556":"1.72044063","0.00672769":"4.40295148","0.00675300":"15.00000000","0.00679364":"4.40295148","0.00685960":"4.40295148","0.00688560":"1.30512280","0.00690000":"50.00000000","0.00691214":"1.07609877","0.00692298":"36.00000000","0.00692556":"4.40295148","0.00694834":"5.16486770","0.00695914":"240.70466273","0.00695954":"6.00000000","0.00697530":"15.00000000","0.00699202":"1.66176545","0.00705993":"1.48172707","0.00708700":"2.90881521","0.00710000":"15.00000000","0.00712983":"1.48172707","0.00716285":"0.44291883","0.00719973":"1.48172707","0.00720036":"2.43432481","0.00720879":"100.08583662","0.00721155":"0.61693611","0.00726456":"0.44725112","0.00726963":"1.48172707","0.00728782":"2.71244118","0.00730000":"50.00000000","0.00731000":"15.00000000","0.00731396":"0.60512986","0.00732687":"1.22884288","0.00733953":"1.48172708","0.00733960":"300.00000000","0.00735259":"2.07956105","0.00735341":"0.71380442","0.00735605":"0.53226805","0.00736025":"0.52470413","0.00736551":"0.77097125","0.00737307":"0.36657420","0.00737475":"3.66705930","0.00737635":"2.99429959","0.00739350":"2.17615307","0.00739573":"2.60854878","0.00739731":"1.22884292","0.00740615":"0.02398988","0.00741782":"0.68269958","0.00742127":"1.54798545","0.00742410":"0.71380446","0.00742676":"0.53226809","0.00743007":"2.52187210","0.00743633":"0.77097126","0.00743728":"0.64447712","0.00744396":"0.36657423","0.00744564":"3.66705934","0.00745720":"0.57338303","0.00746595":"3.29950328","0.00746685":"2.60854879","0.00748970":"8.59578400","0.00749264":"1.54798545","0.00750000":"97.52743449","0.00750950":"0.64447712","0.00752135":"5.00000000","0.00752315":"0.71705582","0.00754778":"0.61810761","0.00755664":"3.53968783","0.00758171":"0.64447713","0.00763100":"15.00000000","0.00763946":"0.68477511","0.00764285":"10.00000000","0.00765569":"1351.95460075","0.00765600":"23.82568625","0.00766100":"9.15686275","0.00766395":"3.35329190","0.00768434":"7.84560000","0.00769595":"6.00000000","0.00770000":"68.70019724","0.00773226":"0.80774511","0.00777278":"3.77858515","0.00777777":"990.89110098","0.00782618":"0.98911342","0.00783744":"1794.31986586","0.00785000":"152.63004030","0.00785960":"9.53740000","0.00788315":"4.02896933","0.00793731":"0.95718358","0.00796310":"15.00000000","0.00796959":"6.00000000","0.00799509":"7.53854751","0.00800000":"350.85610303","0.00805002":"1.08128391","0.00808300":"496.39983125","0.00810000":"65.00000000","0.00811535":"14.45293785","0.00811989":"0.00595451","0.00816433":"1.49496735","0.00816660":"5.52203767","0.00820387":"460.06364638","0.00821434":"38.85548776","0.00824950":"7.90954937","0.00825744":"6.76158731","0.00827854":"5.83678779","0.00828026":"0.69329340","0.00828916":"0.37534076","0.00829000":"28.00146914","0.00829300":"63896.50669264","0.00830000":"520.48192771","0.00831000":"15.00000000","0.00831288":"1.50419508","0.00835774":"6.85021563","0.00840000":"119.04761904","0.00841202":"399.04052396","0.00845236":"565.63882911","0.00845926":"1.17561923","0.00848663":"14.36942888","0.00849586":"8.75670000","0.00850000":"167.64705882","0.00850529":"1.45304978","0.00857171":"0.38933423","0.00858740":"6.10814648","0.00860000":"116.27906976","0.00860548":"1.28683076","0.00863100":"15.00000000","0.00870000":"114.94252873","0.00873170":"100.00000000","0.00875701":"1.30712959","0.00879000":"187.63016831","0.00879088":"116.00000000","0.00879695":"6.00000000","0.00880000":"515.63636363","0.00880001":"17.60687230","0.00882910":"1.63681044","0.00885126":"65.00000000","0.00887342":"0.31781450","0.00887850":"2.86550000","0.00888130":"1.94320811","0.00888150":"15.30355171","0.00888880":"90.84767503","0.00890000":"162.35955056","0.00896310":"15.00000000","0.00900000":"1666.36500369","0.00900126":"25.00000000","0.00902989":"1.56002337","0.00910000":"109.89010989","0.00910171":"414.07152978","0.00920000":"108.69565217","0.00921804":"333.00000000","0.00929542":"528.99090493","0.00930000":"157.52688172","0.00933000":"427.32301746","0.00940000":"106.38297872","0.00948760":"8.78564000","0.00950000":"105.26315789","0.00952135":"5.00000000","0.00952263":"50.00000000","0.00960000":"104.16666666","0.00967627":"1.33678031","0.00969595":"6.10814648","0.00970000":"103.09278350","0.00979658":"330.00000000","0.00980000":"102.04081632","0.00980490":"0.43677908","0.00985700":"2.00000000","0.00987969":"5.99633843","0.00989674":"2.74563000","0.00990000":"101.01010101","0.00991000":"15880.64250868","0.00992120":"438.12705103","0.00997779":"1.75730618","0.01000000":"215.99500625","0.01010000":"99.00990099","0.01020000":"98.03921568","0.01030000":"97.08737864","0.01040000":"96.15384615","0.01048956":"8.74345000","0.01050000":"95.23809523","0.01059572":"325.95207264","0.01060000":"94.33962264","0.01069202":"1.39154562","0.01070000":"93.45794392","0.01079000":"2.98535000","0.01080000":"92.59259259","0.01083415":"0.45340897","0.01086000":"33.01620583","0.01089850":"2.83445000","0.01099492":"12.21629296","0.01100000":"456.86935122","0.01102519":"2.41781317","0.01148487":"209.45414745","0.01148785":"8.46450000","0.01157537":"442.67446426","0.01181440":"2.44353480","0.01185700":"2.00000000","0.01186000":"70.00000000","0.01189670":"2.85645000","0.01197145":"0.69684899","0.01218254":"2.59956533","0.01234980":"344.92682456","0.01244000":"224.00000000","0.01245236":"500.00000000","0.01248670":"7.64534000","0.01278950":"2.75463000","0.01299330":"664.74346385","0.01299518":"6.10814648","0.01300000":"26.14634015","0.01305460":"2.63148534","0.01322813":"0.81989766","0.01330000":"59.85000000","0.01347574":"3.00000000","0.01348795":"7.58485000","0.01352135":"5.00000000","0.01385782":"1122.47921946","0.01399780":"2.74743400","0.01416643":"780.97652730","0.01442498":"3.91128602","0.01457450":"7.45630000","0.01460000":"500.25659354","0.01461673":"0.86053066","0.01487446":"2.40841162","0.01487680":"2.47570000","0.01490000":"359.49307130","0.01496804":"5.02391716","0.01499991":"35627.78290763","0.01500001":"53620.71957921","0.01501427":"32153.24270152","0.01502411":"18769.84433720","0.01512411":"26587.76728056","0.01522421":"965.65121963","0.01547574":"3.00000000","0.01553764":"7.47450000","0.01559910":"444.50306311","0.01585000":"1.18000000","0.01585700":"2.00000000","0.01589670":"3.54646000","0.01593922":"3.73750978","0.01600000":"19.66779705","0.01615109":"0.85424380","0.01623222":"4.00000000","0.01649860":"7.85685600","0.01652263":"50.00000000","0.01687456":"2.13245000","0.01721943":"1249.39868463","0.01747574":"3.00000000","0.01748876":"3.84755000","0.01752135":"5.00000000","0.01763499":"40.00000000","0.01769056":"222.90722050","0.01771026":"4.09100407","0.01785000":"1.65000000","0.01789850":"3.23440000","0.01794567":"0.93218628","0.01836356":"2.26718172","0.01848345":"0.96667613","0.01855940":"2.50000000","0.01857870":"3.74567400","0.01880046":"519.22000000","0.01887840":"0.37478926","0.01900000":"289.27500000","0.01900003":"2.99000000","0.01947574":"3.00000000","0.01948870":"3.05670000","0.01967808":"4.29307058","0.01974468":"155.54450638","0.01985700":"2.00000000","0.01989640":"3.27567000","0.02048750":"7.85684500","0.02055940":"2.80000000","0.02084850":"2.46653000","0.02088998":"1.00000000","0.02147574":"3.00000000","0.02155940":"3.20000000","0.02186454":"4.18708489","0.02188998":"1.00000000","0.02287600":"2.32455000","0.02313906":"1.20544514","0.02347574":"3.00000000","0.02426782":"3.48000000","0.02429395":"3.79222177","0.02488778":"1.65785734","0.02548920":"5.11258841","0.02553138":"4.00000000","0.02687970":"2.17547000","0.02699329":"3.90504446","0.02747574":"2.47000000","0.02752135":"5.00000000","0.02800000":"11.45549490","0.02886780":"1.80637441","0.02963864":"2.73294238","0.03105389":"3.50000000","0.03142188":"0.59212958","0.03171335":"5.12116076","0.03230000":"0.04987500","0.03234763":"4.66381128","0.03286580":"2.47567000","0.03433946":"3.00000000","0.03468676":"1.81710545","0.03487865":"2.46364000","0.03538051":"1.71297166","0.03626086":"1.01045837","0.03666666":"110.22969551","0.03672498":"1.26544297","0.03745949":"1.57691042","0.03752135":"5.00000000","0.03786780":"2.19021650","0.03900000":"10.00000000","0.04030642":"1.27916410","0.04135440":"0.70097846","0.04485600":"1.74550000","0.04666666":"136.95641473","0.04845600":"1.78810800","0.05000000":"15.53608644","0.05433946":"3.00000000","0.05488750":"7.67800000","0.05666666":"0.77374524","0.05752135":"5.00000000","0.05856745":"8.74574700","0.06013189":"30.00000000","0.06037434":"1.20796272","0.06485680":"9.66760000","0.06666666":"0.85971694","0.06725702":"0.27484817","0.06895464":"10.85674560","0.07000000":"5.80970714","0.07433946":"3.00000000","0.07496700":"9.85645000","0.07752135":"5.00000000","0.07896757":"11.74575400","0.08489786":"12.76574000","0.08802941":"200.00000000","0.08802942":"1200.00000000","0.08886470":"10.56754630","0.09433946":"3.00000000","0.09475480":"10.24574570","0.09878760":"8.85687000","0.10000000":"6.00000000","0.10236135":"3.60045582","0.10895467":"7.85654760","0.12856000":"6.78547450","0.14339460":"3.00000000","0.14856750":"4.74574500","0.16666666":"0.95524105","0.18580000":"3.97411460","0.23023199":"5.00000000","0.23023200":"2936.92260841","0.26666666":"1.06137894","0.34339460":"3.00000000","0.36666666":"1.17930993","0.43401216":"347.48562982","0.46666666":"1.31034437","0.54610600":"3.60000000","0.56666666":"1.45593819","0.66666666":"1.61770910","0.76666666":"1.79745456","0.86666665":"200.00000000","0.86666666":"301.99717173","0.87666666":"2.21907970","0.87966666":"2.46564411","0.87996666":"2.73960457","0.87999666":"3.04400507","0.99999998":"1.56830975","1.00000000":"4883.62583027","2.00000000":"133.13949211","2.09266630":"1.34755532","2.99999666":"8.09060055","2.99999998":"1.39695867","9.00000000":"100.00000000","10.00000000":"6.10000000","998.00000000":"100.00000000","999.00000000":"5.00000000"},{"0.00229138":"38.10287686","0.00227997":"7.20868129","0.00217907":"0.25992533","0.00217880":"7.73820000","0.00217785":"0.93328858","0.00217604":"5.89965342","0.00216743":"1.66159614","0.00215885":"0.05500000","0.00215082":"0.11000000","0.00214977":"0.05500000","0.00214273":"0.05500000","0.00214099":"0.05500000","0.00214046":"0.05500000","0.00213995":"6.03084184","0.00213993":"0.05500000","0.00213899":"18.65815174","0.00213752":"0.05500000","0.00213694":"0.05500000","0.00213556":"0.22000000","0.00212801":"0.05500000","0.00212357":"0.05500000","0.00212318":"0.05500000","0.00212252":"0.05500000","0.00212178":"0.05500000","0.00211765":"0.05500000","0.00211702":"0.05500000","0.00211701":"0.05500000","0.00211516":"0.05500000","0.00211139":"0.05500000","0.00211137":"0.05500000","0.00211118":"0.05500000","0.00211029":"0.11000000","0.00210769":"0.11000000","0.00210753":"0.16500000","0.00210724":"0.05500000","0.00210676":"0.05500000","0.00210607":"0.11000000","0.00210522":"0.11000000","0.00210407":"0.11000000","0.00210398":"0.11000000","0.00210300":"0.05500000","0.00210248":"0.11000000","0.00209091":"0.05500000","0.00206181":"0.05500000","0.00206173":"0.05500000","0.00205796":"0.05500000","0.00205740":"0.05500000","0.00204882":"0.05500000","0.00203811":"0.05500000","0.00203222":"1.75484097","0.00202450":"7.57330205","0.00199618":"0.05500000","0.00199617":"0.05500000","0.00196735":"0.05500000","0.00196105":"0.05500000","0.00195227":"0.05500000","0.00193534":"0.05500000","0.00193533":"0.05500000","0.00193532":"0.11000000","0.00191740":"0.05500000","0.00188504":"0.33000000","0.00187707":"0.05500000","0.00187469":"0.05500000","0.00187466":"166.85951847","0.00186029":"0.29134534","0.00185901":"13.39935428","0.00183710":"272.16808557","0.00183682":"50.01300819","0.00180000":"114.99999999","0.00178943":"465.94992831","0.00177007":"100.00000000","0.00175029":"0.81162956","0.00175026":"364.67284600","0.00173936":"40.00000000","0.00166600":"15.00600240","0.00156660":"31.91625175","0.00150007":"100.00000000","0.00150002":"100.00000000","0.00147507":"100.00000000","0.00146617":"500.00000000","0.00139100":"65.00000000","0.00110000":"9.09090909","0.00102337":"100.00000000","0.00102330":"232.64500000","0.00100007":"2000.00000000","0.00100000":"89999.99999000","0.00049173":"500.00000000","0.00049172":"6101.03310827","0.00039000":"127.82000000","0.00012871":"500.00000000","0.00003517":"1000.00000000","0.00003508":"3000.00000000","0.00003507":"7585.43632594","0.00001288":"1000.00000000","0.00001287":"23310.02331002","0.00000222":"10000.00000000","0.00000200":"10000.00000000","0.00000137":"7777.00000000","0.00000130":"10000.00000000","0.00000129":"232558.13953488","0.00000100":"7300.00000000","0.00000017":"3000.00000000","0.00000011":"100000.00000000","0.00000010":"73000.00000000","0.00000003":"100000.00000000","0.00000002":"50000000.00000000","0.00000001":"1972363.00000000"}]}]]]
```

Thats what i currently have:
https://ybin.me/p/a825152ddcde634a#JRwWC5wW2BA2bkiWEBllEy4+sJ0VPPs9KSzU21bJqUs=
Im adding external link because of the limit of the message in here.
And the error that i get is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MasterData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

EDIT: Thank you for your answers.After that inital data the feed uses different format.

```
[132,36988065,[["o",1,"2.84200012","0.00000000"],["o",1,"2.84200014","0.29990442"]]]
```

Here is the class I have tried to create, but im getting same exception error as stated above.

```
public class Small
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public long Seq { get; set; }
            public InnerObjectSmall Obj { get; set; }
        }
        public class InnerObjectSmall
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public int OrderType { get; set; }
            public List<Dictionary<decimal, decimal>> orderBook { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Please show what you have it C# already.

Comment: Unfortunately the structure of the json makes writing a simple C# class that maps to this difficult. The root array contains numbers and arrays, and then more nested arrays, the part that could be mapped to a C# object is the object that contains `currentcyPair`.

Comment: A good example for "A JSON you should never return" :o)

Comment: @SirRufo I don't know who created that json, but I'm sure they hate the dev who has to consume it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create some custom `JsonConverter`s to achieve this. Based on the data, and without any knowledge of the logic behind the data this is what I came up with :

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasterData>(beginingDataRaw);
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MasterDataConverter))]
public class MasterData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long Seq { get; set; }
    public List<InnerObjects> Obj { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(InnerObjectsConverter))]
public class InnerObjects
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public OrderData Data { get; set; } 
}

public class OrderData
{
    public string currencyPair { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> orderBook { get; set; }
}

class InnerObjectsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(InnerObjects);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = new InnerObjects();
        value.Id = reader.ReadAsString();
        reader.Read();
        value.Data = serializer.Deserialize<OrderData>(reader);
        reader.Read();
        return value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class MasterDataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            var value = new MasterData
            {
                Id = (int)reader.ReadAsInt32(),
                Seq = (long)(decimal)reader.ReadAsDecimal()
            };
            reader.Read();
            value.Obj = serializer.Deserialize<List<InnerObjects>>(reader);
            reader.Read();
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Some extra handling for invalid data should be added but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really nasty JSON format. Apart from creating your own serializer, you could also manually select and deserialize the appopriate subset. This approach is less robust but sometimes quicker to build for a one-off scenario.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"[130, 18063676, [[""i"", {
        ""currencyPair"": ""XMR_BLK"",
        ""orderBook"": [{
                ""0.00229667"": ""22.10045806"",
                ""0.00229668"": ""2.24052467"",
                ""0.00230580"": ""0.66824024"",
                // ...
            }
        ]
    }
    ]]]";

    var outerArray = JArray.Parse(json);

    var innerNestedArray = outerArray[2];

    var iOrderBookArray = innerNestedArray[0];

    var orderBookElement = iOrderBookArray[1];

    var orderBook = orderBookElement.ToObject<OrderBook>();

    var orderLines = orderBook.orderBook[0].ToList();
}

public class OrderBook
{
    public string currencyPair { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] orderBook { get; set; }
}
```